# Delete a node from a list in D3 and reset layout

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, collision-detection

I am trying to edit the collision detection program available at http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html

I am trying to edit the code so that it had labels on each node and I can delete nodes by stopping the animation and clicking on the node that I want to delete. Here is what the edited code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.geom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.layout.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">

circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="body">
      <div id="footer">
        Collision Detection
        <div class="hint">move the mouse to repel nodes</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var width = 1280,
    height = 800;

var labels = [
    "hello",
    "goodbye",
    "purple",
    "blue",
    "green",
    "pink",
    "yellow",
    "white",
    "black",
    "brown",
    "cat",
    "dog",
    "bird",
    "snake",
    "turtle"];

var i = 0;

var nodes = d3.range(200).map(function() { return {radius: Math.random() * 12 + 4, label: labels[Math.floor(Math.random() * 15 )]}; }),
    root = nodes[0],
    color = d3.scale.category10();

root.radius = 0;
root.fixed = true;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
    .nodes(nodes)
    .size([width, height]);

force.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

g = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes.slice(1))
  .enter().append("g")

    g.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 0)
    .attr('cy', 0)
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i % 20); })

    g.append('text')
    .text(function(d){return d.label})
    .attr('x', -15)
    .attr('y', 5)

force.on("tick", function(e) {
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;

  while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(nodes[i]));

  svg.selectAll("g")
  .attr('transform', function(d){return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"})
});

svg.on("mousemove", function() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  //force.resume();
});

svg.on("click", function() {
    if(force.alpha()) {
    force.stop();
    } else {
    force.resume();
    }
});

svg.selectAll("g").on("click", function() {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    this.remove();
    //nodes.removeChild(this.remove());
    //var deleteNode = this.selection.node();

  force.on("tick", function(x) {
    var a = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
        b = 0,
        c = nodes.length;

    while(++b < c) a.visit(collide(nodes[b]));

    //svg.selectAll("g")
    //.attr('transform', function(d){return "translate("+d.x+"."+d.y+")"})
  });

});


function collide(node) {
  var r = node.radius + 16,
      nx1 = node.x - r,
      nx2 = node.x + r,
      ny1 = node.y - r,
      ny2 = node.y + r;
  return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
      var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
          y = node.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
      if (l < r) {
        l = (l - r) / l * .5;
        node.x -= x *= l;
        node.y -= y *= l;
        quad.point.x += x;
        quad.point.y += y;
      }
    }
    return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
  };
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am having trouble with is deleting the node from the array of nodes and resetting the layout. Right now it hides the actual circle and label, but when the animation restarts, it still has a spot where the node didn't actually delete.

```
svg.selectAll("g").on("click", function() {
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
        this.remove();
        //nodes.removeChild(this.remove());
        //var deleteNode = this.selection.node();
        //nodes.removeChild(deleteNode);

      force.on("tick", function(x) {
        var a = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
            b = 0,
            c = nodes.length;

        while(++b < c) a.visit(collide(nodes[b]));

        //svg.selectAll("g")
        //.attr('transform', function(d){return "translate("+d.x+"."+d.y+")"})
      });

    });
```

As you can see I used this.remove() to hide the node, but it doesn't actually delete the node. The code under that is other things that I have tried in order to delete the node and then reset the layout, but none where successful. I'm not really familiar with D3 and I am having trouble understanding what is going on, and actually deleting a node from an array in D3.

Answer (score 1):

To restart the layout after delete of a node

```
svg.selectAll("g").on("click", function() {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    this.remove();
    force.resume();//restart the layout
});
```

Clicking on the svg will stop the tick clicking it back will start the tick layout again

```
svg.on("click", function() {
    if(force.alpha()) {
    force.stop();
    } else {
    force.resume();//start the layout
    }
});
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/8t1Lgsk6/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bit late, but you haven't solved it completely. The node gets deleted from the DOM but not from the data. So I've added my own answer to add to yours :)) Hopefully it helps others

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is almost there. You delete the element but you dont delete it from the data. So I edited the fiddle and added this :

```
svg.selectAll("g").on("click", function(d) {
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
    this.remove();
    force.resume();

    nodes.splice(d.index,1) //this deletes the node from the data at the nodes index
     console.log(nodes.length)
});
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8t1Lgsk6/2/

Comment: Thanks for finding that bug +1 :)